# HTML - <Li> last character showing as first character

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm learning HTML/CSS. I created a List that is justified to the right. In order to do this I created the following CSS code:

```
li {

    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;


}
```

And the HTML does not have anything special:

```
<div class="row">
<div class= "col-12" >
  <ul >
    <li>Corrientes Eddy (ECT)</li>
    <li>Corrientes Eddy Multi frecuencia para Intercambiadores de Calor (ECT)</li>
    <li>Ultrasonido Arreglo de Fases (PA)</li>
    <li>Ultrasonido Industrial (UT)</li>
    <li>Ultrasonido para Medición de Espesores (UTM)</li>
    <li>Inspección Visual (VT)</li>
    <li>Inspección Visual Remota (RVT)</li>
    <li>Líquidos Penetrantes (PT)</li>
    <li>Partículas Magnéticas (MT)</li>
    <li>Pruebas de Dureza (HT)</li>
    <li>Pruebas Hidrostáticas y Neumáticas (LT)</li>
    <li>Radiografía con Rayos X Industriales (RT)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On a PC the list looks as it should, but on a phone, the last parenthesis becomes the first character, I'm not sure if this is a result of the direction parameter. Any ideas?
I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Something else to note: I have a second list with the same css but that one does not have parenthesis and it shows ok.

[how it looks on a pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPKEw.png)

[how it looks on a mobile phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8paUk.png)

**Update:**
So far this is what I tried:
I removed direction from the CSS and used dir in the HTML
I removed my parenthesis and used these ﹙﹚, （ ）, ( )
I removed my parenthesis and used the opening and closing parenthesis code (( and ))
I added a space with  
I changed the CSS from li and used it on ul
I removed my UL tags from html
I added a point and now the point shows as first character on both the PC and mobile (but on mobile it shows the point and the parenthesis)

[I added a point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEClz.png)

Comment: Does changing <list> into <ul> work? Because <list> is not a standard html object, it may cause the browser to render things differently.

Comment: thanks @Jae for pointing this out, I don't know how I missed that, but I did the change and I still have the problem on mobile. I'm trying to open the site on safari and chrome, both show the same. Something else to note. This only happens on list items that end with a parenthesis. I have a second list that does not have parenthesis and I get no errors there.

Comment: I would like you to retype the last part and try using these characters and see if it changes the behaviors. ﹙﹚, （ ）, ( ) . There might be a hidden character breaking the rtl in your data.

Comment: @Jae The 3 parenthesis variants look good on the PC but again, the phone throws the last parenthesis to the beginning of the line. You made me think about this and I even added a space (&nbsp;) to see if that was moved instead of the parenthesis but I got no luck.

Comment: The CSS specification [advises against using `direction`](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-writing-modes-4/#direction). It's hard to get right consistently. Instead you should use the [HTML `dir` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attr-dir)

Comment: @alohci thanks for the suggestion, I was not aware this was possible. I got the same results. This is the code I tried <li dir="rtl">Corrientes Eddy (ECT)</li>

Comment: Why are you using `direction: rtl;` on a language that is not left to right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try styling on the `<ul>` instead of `<li>` ?

```
 ul {
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
 }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. No luck. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying direction right to left. Why?

See [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction):

> "Use rtl for languages written from right to left (like Hebrew or
> Arabic), and ltr for those written from left to right (like English
> and most other languages)."

For a right to left language the system has to look for paired characters - e.g. all the different bracket types - and make sure that any closing item of the pair comes to the left of its opening partner. Hence your bracket gets moved.

But you are using a left to right language. Normally no need to specify direction as it'll be the default.